# Getting a DNS error when launching Jenkins.war

Tags: java, jenkins, dns, hudson

I'm running a brand new instance of Jenkins in a Windows 7 environment with no luck.  I run the war file from the command line by typing java -jar .\jenkins.war

**I keep getting this error:**

```
D:\Development\Jenkins>java -jar .\jenkins.war <br>
Running from: D:\Development\Jenkins\jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Dec 04, 2014 9:51:47 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Dec 04, 2014 9:51:49 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-winstone-2.8
Dec 04, 2014 9:51:50 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Jenkins home directory: C:\Users\whamidy\.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Dec 04, 2014 9:51:51 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
Dec 04, 2014 9:51:51 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Dec 04, 2014 9:51:51 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Dec 04, 2014 9:52:05 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Dec 04, 2014 9:52:05 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Dec 04, 2014 9:52:05 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Dec 04, 2014 9:52:05 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Dec 04, 2014 9:52:05 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Dec 04, 2014 9:52:08 AM org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD start
INFO: Started SSHD at port 61733
Dec 04, 2014 9:52:08 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization<br>
Dec 04, 2014 9:52:08 AM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running <br><br>
←[33mDec 04, 2014 9:52:27 AM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: 16FBE3C38086BE0B
←[0m←[33mDec 04, 2014 9:52:28 AM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: 416A5FB5808B6868
←[0m←[33mDec 04, 2014 9:52:37 AM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: 416A5FB5808B6868
←[0m←[33mDec 04, 2014 9:52:47 AM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: DA41FBD3D9C06F35
←[0m←[33mDec 04, 2014 9:55:07 AM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: DA41FBD3D9C06F35
←[0m←[33mDec 04, 2014 9:55:34 AM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: DA41FBD3D9C06F35
←[0m←[33mDec 04, 2014 9:57:15 AM javax.jmdns.impl.DNSIncoming readAnswer
WARNING: There was an OPT answer. Not currently handled. Option code: 65002 data: 5E08AD25F5182E2C
```

**When I launch the browser I get this error:**

Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)

Please confirm you typed your URL correctly.
Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS.

For assistance, contact your network support team.

Thanks

Comment: I've been trying to access Jenkins by hitting localhost:8080.  I just tried hitting it with my system IP and it worked.